# Linking 2 tables to display readable statistics

Tags: php, database

Alright lets get at it.

I have 2 tables, one is for storing the options that can be selected and another is for storing how many people selected the option.

So table 1:

```
id, option_name, description
```

Table 2:

```
id, chosen_by_who
```

basically if "John" chooses "Cat" (which has id: 3 in table 1) my script will insert 
`(3, john)` and if 5 people chose "cat" there would be 5 counts of "cat" so thats how I plan to make my statistics.

Problem is in my statistics it says: "3" was chosen by 5 people.

I want it to say "Cat" was chosen by 5 people.

Since Cat has the same ID in table 1, I want to link them and define 3 as cat.

This is how I count my statistics:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT  `optionid` , COUNT(  `optionid` ) AS times 
                        FROM  `has_picked` GROUP BY  `optionid`");
$query->execute();
```

So basically I want to define 1 as dog, 2 as rabbit, 3 as cat and so on

Answer (score 1):

You have to `JOIN` these tables, so you can access columns from both of them:

```
 SELECT  
     t2.option_name, 
     COUNT(t1.optionid) AS times 
 FROM  
     has_picked t1
 JOIN
     my_options t2 ON(t2.id = t1.optionid)
 GROUP BY  
     t1.optionid
```

Answer (score 0):

To combine rows from multiple tables consider using a [JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) clause

```
SELECT 
    table1.id, 
    table1.option_name, 
    COUNT(table1.id) AS times
FROM table2
JOIN table1 ON (table1.id = table2.id)
GROUP BY
    table2.id
```

Comment: Hi, your post has been flagged as "low quality", probably because it consists solely of code. You could massively improve your answer by providing an explanation of exactly how and why this answers the question?